# Where exactly am I going wrong with this XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd-validation

I'm trying to write an XSD document

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:books" xmlns:bks="urn:books">
 <xsd:element name="Books" type="bks:BooksForm"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Book"    type="bks:BookForm"  minOccurs="0"     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Author"   type="bks:AuthorForm" minOccurs="1"  /><!--1-->
      <xsd:element name="Isbn"    type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="Title"    type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="xsd:string"  minOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="YearValue" type="bks:YearForm" minOccurs="1" /><!--2-->
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Cover"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="AuthorForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Name"   type="bks:NameForm"/><!--1-->
      <xsd:element name="Contact"    type="bks:ContactForm"/> <!--2-->
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="YearForm">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Year"   type="xsd:integer"/><!--1-->
        </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Edition"   type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="NameForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="First"   type="xsd:string"/><!--1-->
      <xsd:element name="Last"    type="xsd:string"/> <!--2-->
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ContactForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Phone"   type="xsd:string"/><!--1-->
     </xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:attribute name="Office"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

that matches with the following XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Courses.xsl"?>
<Books>
  <Book Cover="Paper back">
    <Isbn>978-1-4652-0558-2</Isbn>
    <Title>Service-Oriented Computing</Title>
    <Author>
      <Name>
        <First>John</First>
        <Last>Doe</Last>
      </Name>
      <Contact Office="BY400">
        <Phone>480-965 000</Phone>
      </Contact>
    </Author>
    <Publisher>Kendall Hunt</Publisher>
    <Year Edition="3">
      <Year>2012</Year>
    </Year>
  </Book>
....</Books>
```

However I'm getting the following error, when I try to validate it online

```
Line 3, 8   cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Books'.
```

But as far as I can see, Ive declared it correctly. Can anyone point out what Im doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Can you add the xsd that defines books to this question?

Comment: Im not sure if I'm missing something, as Im new to XML and XSD, but there is just ONE XSD and its corresponding XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is actually with this line:
`<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:books" xmlns:bks="urn:books">`

`books` is not capitalized here like it is elsewhere in the document.

Here's a more "complete" fix:

I did several things.  First, I removed the `targetNamespace` and `xmlns:bks` parts.  Then I reordered some items in the `BookForm` type, fixed `YearValue` to be `Year` as it is in the xml data.  Then I removed all references to `bks`.  It now validates.

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsd:element name="Books" type="BooksForm"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Book"    type="BookForm"  minOccurs="0"     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Isbn"    type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="Title"    type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="Author"   type="AuthorForm" minOccurs="1"  /><!--1-->
      <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="xsd:string"  minOccurs="1" />
      <xsd:element name="Year" type="YearForm" minOccurs="1" /><!--2-->
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Cover"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="AuthorForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Name"   type="NameForm"/><!--1-->
      <xsd:element name="Contact"    type="ContactForm"/> <!--2-->
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="YearForm">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Year"   type="xsd:integer"/><!--1-->
        </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="Edition"   type="xsd:integer"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="NameForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="First"   type="xsd:string"/><!--1-->
      <xsd:element name="Last"    type="xsd:string"/> <!--2-->
    </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ContactForm">
    <xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:element name="Phone"   type="xsd:string"/><!--1-->
     </xsd:sequence>
     <xsd:attribute name="Office"   type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: If you meant to modify it to `<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Books" xmlns:bks="urn:Books"`. It doesnt help

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a new XSD for you; hopefully it meets your needs:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Books">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Book">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Isbn"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Title"/>
              <xs:element name="Author">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Name">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="First"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Last"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Contact">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Phone"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Office"/>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Publisher"/>
              <xs:element name="Year">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="Year"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="Edition"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Cover"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Perhaps a better approach to rewriting the OPs work would be to explain what the problem with his schema is.  The question, after all, was a request to point out what's wrong.  He appears to want to learn something from the experience.

Comment: @ChrisLively honestly I'm not sure.  I'm at work and I don't have time to look into it, but I can gladly give him something that works.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9, the entity Books is supposed to contain multiple Book instances. I dont think your XSD supports that

Answer (score 1):

I dont see nothing wrong with your XSD, but with the XML.
You are missing the namespace specification in your XMl.
It should read: `<Books xmlns="urn:books">`